# MySQL join not returning all results

Tags: mysql

`SELECT * FROM products AS p
JOIN images AS i
ON (p.id = i.product_id)`

I want this query also to return results where there are no fields in "images" related to "products". How do I do that?

Comment: This is the definition of what a LEFT JOIN does. It returns at least one row for the table on the left, even if there are no rows in the table on the right that match the join condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `OUTER` join.

```
SELECT *
FROM   products AS p
       LEFT JOIN images AS i
         ON ( p.id = i.product_id )
```

`LEFT` because you want to preserve all rows from the left (first) table.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use LEFT JOIN:

```
   SELECT * FROM 
      products AS p LEFT JOIN images AS i ON p.id = i.product_id;
```